# Return the number of occurrences of a number

Tags: excel

[image]

Right now my issue, is that if I want to search for '263', it returns 0 as I believe excel thinks the entire cell is one string.

I have tried using FIND and SEARCH but it doesn't return the correct number.

Comment: Have you considered countif() with wildcards?

Comment: you could take a look at this article for more advanced searches, examples there include extracting numbers from strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697

Comment: Please show the exact formulas you have tried. As @SolarMike writes, you can use `COUNTIF` with wild cards.  However, if there might be more than a single `263` in a cell, and you need to count both, you could use `FILTERXML` depending on your version of Excel.

Comment: @SolarMike: as you can see, my answer contains the formula `=COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*263*")`. Unfortunately, when the cell contains only the number 263, then that cell won't be counted. Do you know why and do you have a simple solution for that?

Comment: @Dominique so have 2 countif() like so: COUNTIF(A1:A6,263)+COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*263*") but a helper column or text-to-columns may be an easier option...

Answer (score 1):

I just managed as follows:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*263*")
```

Be aware that an entry like `263 lab | 263` will yield 2 count results.

Comment: Not so.  `COUNTIF` will only return 1 count no matter how many `263`'s are in a cell. Try: `A1 = 263 lab | 263`.  `B1: = OUNTIF(A1,"*263")`.  Result => `1`

Answer (score 0):

So, just to clarify my comment adding to @Dominique :

[image]

And, you will notice it only captures 1 for the entry in cell A5

You can try each of the following:

```
COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*263*")

COUNTIF(A1:A6,"263*")

COUNTIF(A1:A6,"*263")

COUNTIF(A1:A6,263)
```

Separately to see what happens.